# I am trying to kill the dsmcad service, but getting "global name 'dsmcad' is not defined"

Tags: service, restart

```
import os
import signal
from subprocess import check_output

def get_pid(name):
    return check_output(["pidof", name])

def main():
    os.kill(get_pid(dsmcad), signal.SIGTERM) #or signal.SIGKILL 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in main
NameError: global name 'dsmcad' is not defined
```

Comment: Is `dsmcad` supposed to be surrounded by quotes to make it a string?

Comment: I am trying to kill a process name called as dsmcad. Is there way to kill the process?

Comment: You'll probably need to put quotes around `dsmcad`. You can just give python some arbitrary undeclared identifier and expect it to understand what you want.

Comment: You can't*. I should have noticed that typo when I posted it.